# Strings from JSON response not escaped correctly in HTML markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, escaping

I have a JSON response with strings escaped as follows: `24"` escaped as `24&#34` (no semicolon)

When I write this string to markup with JQuery .text(), the final result appears as `24&amp;#34` in the generated markup (the `&` in `24&#34` is HTML escaped).

Is there a good way to display this text correclty in the browser (i.e. `24"` instead of `24&#34`)?

Comment: Is "fix your server to send back non-broken data" an option?

Comment: I agree with mu is too short about fixing the server being the best solution, but if you apply it as .html() rather than .text(), it may have the effect you're looking for.

Comment: What about just adding a semicolon to the end of the string you send to `.text()`?

Comment: The text is arbitrary and these escape sequences can lie anywhere within a string.I don't think I can fix the data, since we get it this way from somewhere, and I wasn't sure that it was broken to begin with (or just some other format). Using .html() worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try .html() instead of .text() and the data you are getting is coming from database?